# MS SQL Server repair umlauts?

Tags: sql, diacritics

Is there any possibility to repair my umlauts in my sql table ?

```
For Example this: 
Test ausf³hren --> Test ausführen
```

I have searched a lot, but i haven't any idea ?

Comment: _Repair_ means to get `ausführen` out of `ausf³hren`? I assume that this is impossible without a german dictionary table including all conjugations and declinations.

Comment: Any idea how that got there in the first place?

Comment: Repair means to replace the umlauts in a string ? But i dont know the values for example ³ is the value for ü and so son

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically speaking, just do this: `REPLACE(N'³', N'ü')`. There are just a handful of German characters that need this treatment.

If you want an exact solution, you need to find out what encoding was (incorrectly) used to create the garbled strings. Then you would use this encoding to convert back to bytes, then convert the resulting bytes to a string using the true encoding that gives correct results.